# ¿Como usar el botón X en un form de Java para poner una ventana emergente?

Tags: java, windows-forms

Uso eclipse y no puedo usar el evento:

```
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
}
```

como puedo hacer para usar la x del form para poder usarlo como si fuese un botón normal para hacer una ventana emergente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar añadiendo un WindowsListener a tu Frame y usar la función WindowClosing, aunque esta función también se activaría si cerrases tu ventana de otra forma que no fuese pulsando el botón de cerrar.

```
frame1 = new JFrame();
frame1.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() { 
        public void windowClosing( WindowEvent evt ) { 
            int opcion = 0;

            opcion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame1, "¿Seguro que desea cerrar el programa?", "Aviso",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            switch (opcion) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                break;
            case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    } );
```

Otra forma sería ocultar los botones de minimizar, cerrar, etc. usando, por ejemplo, setUndecorated(), crearlos tú y darle las funciones que quieras.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias me sirve, solo cerrare el from de esa forma por el momento.